# Unable to restore a nuget of .net core class lib into another

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I am trying to create a nuget for a class library which I want to be consumed across different applications. This class library is in .net core (4.5.1 framework).

[image: Adding new Class Lib]

The project.json looks like below:

```
    {
  "version": "1.0.0",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http": "1.0.0",
    "log4net": "2.0.8"
  },

  "description": "Logging from .net core",

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": [ "dnxcore50" ]
    }
  }
}
```

I build my class library and create a nuget package and put it in my internal repository. I created nuget package using 2 different ways:

1. create a .nuspec file( command : `nuget spec`) and pack the .nuspec file (command  `nuget pack projectname.nuspec`) -> results in a .nupkg file
2. Command : dotnet pack project.json  -> results in .nupkg and .sysmbols.nupkg files

When I try to restore this package from my repo into another application, I get error : 
for nuget created with method 1 :

```
 Package TestLib 1.0.0 is not compatible with netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6). Package TestLib 1.0.0 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETStandard,Version=v1.6.
```

When I looked into References tree in Solution explorer, I see that the error is on my referenced class library package with message :

```
NU1002 The dependency TestLib does not support framework .NetStandard, version =v1.6
```

For method 2:

Restore will be successful, but I do not get/use any classes from the library. Basically an empty dll reference.

The project.json of my application is simple and straight.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.1"
    },
    "TestLib": "1.0.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

I am going clue less why this behaviour!! Why I am not able to restore a .net core library nuget into another. I also tried restoring to a . net core console application, .net core web application all with same results.

I am using VS2015 ENterprise edition with .netCore tools Preview 2

Comment: Have you tried doing the same with Visual Studio 2017 and the RTM version of the .NET Core SDK? Maybe you'll get a better result, or at least more feedback about why it isn't working?

Comment: Looks like you've targeted your library at 4.5.1 (.net-standard 1.2) but your app is targeting .net-standard 1.6. Try targeting your app at v.1.3. Don't include a screenshot of the error message as it's not searchable, use cut-and-paste instead (add it to your question).

Comment: @Boggin I have updated the question. But from the project.json files of both library and application, I assume that I am targeting right frameworks and app versions. Correct me if wrong.

Comment: @MartinCostello Will give a try

Comment: I tried doing different permutations and combinations. Restore always fails.